# Improve Tree Aspect (forest)

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

Today, I need your help again to deal with the package `forest` (it's a really powerful package, but rather complex also). Basically, I have already spent several hours trying to draw an ultimatum game in tree form that should look like this:

[image]

So far, I have managed to create this code that somehow works (but does not work nicely):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,skip=0pt,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/xlabel near ticks/.style={/pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel}},/pgfplots/ylabel near ticks/.style={/pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{forest}
for tree={l sep=4em, s sep=8em, anchor=center}
[$P_1$, circle, draw, 
    [,name=0, edge label={node[midway,left,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$x=0$}}]
    [$P_2$, l*=2, before computing xy={s=(s("!p")+s("!n"))/2}, circle, draw, edge label={node[midway,right,]{$x$}}
        [{$c-x,x$}, edge label={node[midway,left,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$Y$}}]
        [{$0,0$}, edge label={node[midway,right,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$N$}}]]
    [,name=1, edge label={node[midway,right,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$x=c$}}]]
\draw (0) to[bend right=45] (1);
\end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output I obtain is this one:

[image]

Ideally, the things I'd like to modify are several ones. First, I'd like (a) the curved line to touch the branches of the tree, avoiding that ugly white space. Second, (b) I'd like to avoid the overlap between the curved line and the node P2. Third, (c) I'd like to make sure that the angles of the two branches in the two nodes is the same. In other words, the angle of the second node is wider than that of the first node, and I'd like them to be the same. Fourth, (d) I'd like the branches of the second node to be shorter than those of the first one, if possible. All the questions are equally relevant. Any help with any of the four issues will be greatly appreciated.

P.S.: Ideally, I'd like to stick to my current code as much as possible (in other words, I'd like to apply the minimum necessary changes to the code to obtain the changes I need because this is a code I can understand more or less easily).

Comment: Why loading `pgfplots` in the MWE? I suppose it's not related to this question, no?

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, I was just making sure. :D

Comment: @Clément Sorry, but I think that's just rubbish, frankly. It is much easier to draw *trees* with **forest** if you need power and flexibility. TikZ's built-in stuff is fine for really simple trees, but it is a huge pain for more complex ones, especially for many trees of the same kind. Moreover, you still have access to all of TikZ if you use **forest**. Indeed, you can't help but use TikZ if you use **forest**. I don't think TikZ is *the* way to draw in LaTeX, but it is one of the ways. But **forest** is 'the' way to draw trees using TikZ.

Comment: @cfr You're probably right, I deleted my comment, that was advising Héctor to use TiKz rather than tree, for its flexibility. I don't often see tree in this site, don't use it at all, so my answer was probably biased. I had a quick peek in tree documentation, and did not see anything with arcs or the kind of labels OP asked for. I'm glad to be wrong.

Comment: @Clément What's tree? The point about **forest** is that it is based on TikZ and makes it very easy to use anything from TikZ that you like. For example, my solution below uses a **forest** style which uses `tikz={}` to add TikZ annotations using the `calc` and `through` libraries (though the latter is superfluous, I think). The fact that **forest** doesn't have an arc-drawing-option built-in doesn't matter so long as TikZ supports arcs, which it does. Also, the OP didn't ask anything about labels, as far as I can see. The OP already has the labels done.

Comment: @cfr : sorry, read `forest` instead of tree. I'm willing to admit that drawing repetitively trees is much more simple with `forest` than with plain TikZ. And I don't question `forest`'s handy features. But, as you say, involved drawing as the one OP asks require TikZ, so learning it does not seem superfluous. Probably because I know one and not the other, I tend to think that TikZ remains simpler than `forest` in that particular case (547 characters in Ignasi's answer, 1643 in yours, that's a huge difference). But, since OP asked for a `forest` answer, yours is closer to his requirements.

Comment: Lovely debate, guys. I am actually quite happy to see that I can stick to Forest to draw that tree.

Comment: @Clément Yes, but that's mainly because I tried to build flexibility and automation in. If I was aiming for the shortest code, it would be shorter. But, in any case, I don't think length of code is a good measure of simplicity. And of course knowing TikZ helps because **forest** IS TikZ. This 'either... or...' thing is ridiculous. It's not either or.

Comment: @Clément See below: just for you a 644 character version. (Ignasi's my character count makes 563 so maybe our editors count differently and you will get a different result.) This is achieved by making the code one-off, killing automation, hard-coding stuff rather than using styles, reducing flexibility and relying on human eyes to place labels and ensure consistency of formatting. However, I like the arc better. That's the only bit which eliminates a TikZ method in favour of another Forest feature.... But I still say that yours is a false dichotomy. TikZ is great; Forest *the* tree specialist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After using some of the suggestions posted here and some imagination, I have obtained exactly what I was looking for applying very few changes to my original code. I share the answer because I think it might help others in the future. Here is the output I finally obtain:

[image]

And this is the MWE I am using to obtain it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,skip=0pt,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/xlabel near ticks/.style={/pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel}},/pgfplots/ylabel near ticks/.style={/pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Tree Form of the Ultimatum Game}
\label{Tree Form of the Ultimatum Game P}
\medskip
\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}
[$P_1$, circle, draw, for tree={l sep=4em, s sep=8em, anchor=center, calign=fixed edge angles},
    [, name=0, coordinate, edge label={node[midway,left,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$x=0$}}]
    [$P_2$, name=P2, coordinate, l*=2, before computing xy={s=(s("!p")+s("!n"))/2}, circle, draw, edge label={node[midway,right,]{$x$}}, for tree={l sep=2em, s sep=4em, anchor=center, calign=fixed edge angles},
        [{$c-x,x$}, edge label={node[midway,left,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$Y$}}]
        [{$0,0$}, edge label={node[midway,right,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$N$}}]]
    [, name=1, coordinate, edge label={node[midway,right,outer sep=1.5mm,]{$x=c$}}]]
\draw[dashed,bend right](0)to(P2);
\draw[dashed,bend right](P2)to(1);
\end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The changes in relation to the original code are as follows:

1. Use `coordinate` in each empty node to eliminate the white space between the arc and the end of the branches.
2. Draw two bend right lines instead of only one. Essentially, there is one line that connect the left node with the central node, and another one that connects the central node to the right one. It has been fairly easy, but it took me a while to come with such a simple and good-looking solution.
3. Use `for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}` between `\begin{forest}` to make sure all angles are the same.
4. Use `for tree={l sep=X, s sep=Y, calign=fixed edge angles}` in EACH SINGLE NODE, and choosing smaller values for `X` and `Y` for the smaller nodes. It might not make much sense, but checking the code should make this clear.

PS: I am not using any kind of automatization (yet), as proposed in one of the answers, because I have been using LaTeX for a month and a half now, and I am still trying to grasp the basics.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution which I think meets all the stated desiderata. I assumed, from the target image, that you did not want the arc to fall short of the topmost point of the node `P_2`. If that is not required, you need not bother with some of the calculations involved in my code.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
```

We load `through` and `calc` TikZ libraries to get the arc drawn correctly.

```
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}
\usepackage{forest}
```

Now we set up some styles. Some of these simplify your existing code. If you prefer not to use them, you can omit them.

```
\forestset{%
```

`auto edge label` automates the code for formatting the `edge label`. It creates the node, puts the contents in maths mode and decides whether to put the label to the left or right of the edge. This means that

```
edge label=x^2, auto edge label
```

will do the right thing.

```
  auto edge label/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
```

Don't do anything if it's the root node.

```
      if level=0{}{
```

If the node is in the second half of it's parent's children, or if it is the middle child ...

```
        if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
```

If the node is the middle child ...

```
          if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, right] {$##1$}
            },
          }{
```

If the node is in the second half of it's parent's children ...

```
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right] {$##1$}
            },
          },
        }{
```

If the node is in the first half of it's parent's children ...

```
          edge label/.wrap value={
            node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left] {$##1$}
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

This is the style for nicer empty nodes. It is from page 65 of the current manual. It is part of the `linguistics` library. Hence, if you use that library, you can omit this definition and just apply the style out-of-the-box.

Note that I think the explanation in this part of the manual mistakenly refers to non-existent options, but I'm not certain about this.

```
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
```

Here's the style for drawing the arcs. You pass this as an option to the parent of the nodes through which the arc should be drawn.

No edges are drawn as part of the tree itself except to the second child. If there might be more than 3 children, this would need to get a bit more sophisticated. This code assumes 3 children.

Instead, the arc is drawn afterwards by calculating the appropriate points based on the position of the middle node and the default angle to the nodes when using `calign=fixed edge angles`. The edges to the first and third child are drawn at this time.

[This should really be a bit more sophisticated in terms of checking for various possibilities, but this should work in cases relevantly like the MWE.]

```
  arc below/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \clip (.center) coordinate (o) -- (!1.north) coordinate (a) |- (!2.north) coordinate (b) -| (!3.north) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
      \node [draw, circle through={(b)}] at (o) {};
      \draw [\forestoption{edge}] () -- ($(o)!1!-35:(b)$) ($(o)!1!35:(b)$) -- ();
    },
    for children={
      if n=2{}{no edge},
    }
  }
}
```

Simple TikZ style for convenience.

```
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle}
}
```

Then we can just apply all this stuff to the tree as follows.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
```

From the MWE.

```
    l sep=4em,
    s sep=8em,
```

Apply two of the new styles to the whole tree.

```
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
```

Put all nodes into maths mode to save dollar signs.

```
    math content,
  }
```

Specify the `arc below` style for the root.

```
  [P_1, my circle, arc below
    [, edge label={x=0}]
    [P_2, my circle, edge label=x
      [{c-x,x}, edge label=Y]
      [{0,0}, edge label=N]
    ]
    [, edge label={x=c}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree with styles]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  auto edge label/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      if level=0{}{
        if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
          if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, right] {$##1$}
            },
          }{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right] {$##1$}
            },
          },
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={
            node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left] {$##1$}
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
  arc below/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \clip (.center) coordinate (o) -- (!1.north) coordinate (a) |- (!2.north) coordinate (b) -| (!3.north) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
      \node [draw, circle through={(b)}] at (o) {};
      \draw [\forestoption{edge}] () -- ($(o)!1!-35:(b)$) ($(o)!1!35:(b)$) -- ();
    },
    for children={
      if n=2{}{no edge},
    }
  }
}
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=4em,
    s sep=8em,
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content,
  }
  [P_1, my circle, arc below
    [, edge label={x=0}]
    [P_2, my circle, edge label=x
      [{c-x,x}, edge label=Y]
      [{0,0}, edge label=N]
    ]
    [, edge label={x=c}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If you want to increase the separation between the first two levels of the tree further, the easiest way is to simply increase the value of `l sep` for the root node. Here's a deliberately exaggerated example:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=4em,
    s sep=8em,
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content,
  }
  [P_1, my circle, arc below, l sep*=6
    [, edge label={x=0}]
    [P_2, my circle, edge label=x
      [{c-x,x}, edge label=Y]
      [{0,0}, edge label=N]
    ]
    [, edge label={x=c}]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: increased level separation]

Here the minimum distance between the root and its children is set to be six times the usual minimum distance between levels with `l sep*=6`. If you prefer to add an absolute amount, you could say `l sep+=<dimension>`. Or if you just want to override the default `l sep=<dimension>` specifies the minimum distance precisely.

It is important that what `l sep` ensures is the ***minimum*** distance. So, if `l sep` is set very small for one level and a bit bigger for another, you may end up with the same distance in each case because other factors will mean that **forest** needs the nodes to be spaced at greater distances than either of the specified minimums.

I note that your actual target tree is not, in fact, like the one you showed in the question. In fact, the trickiest part of my code above is not required for your final tree at all.

Here's an automated version of that tree for reference. This version dispenses with the TikZ libraries since they are only needed for `arc below`. `arc through` is a new style which connects to the west and east anchors rather than passing through the north anchor. `my arc` determines the arc's style. This can be set within the tree using `my arcs={<key list>}` to determine the style. By default, it is empty and the arc is draw with the style of the current `edge` option. Specifying the style with `my arcs` allows to supplement or override the `edge` style. For example, the arc may be `densely dashed` even if the edges are solidly drawn.

```
\forestset{%
  arc through/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \path [\forestoption{edge}, my arc] (!1) [out=-35, in=180] to (!2.west) (!2.east) [out=0, in=-145] to (!3);
    }
  },
  my arcs/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      my arc/.style={#1},
    }
  },
}
\tikzset{%
  my arc/.style={},
}
```

[image: dashed arc through]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  auto edge label/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      if level=0{}{
        if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
          if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, right] {$##1$}
            },
          }{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right] {$##1$}
            },
          },
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={
            node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left] {$##1$}
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
  arc through/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \path [\forestoption{edge}, my arc] (!1) [out=-35, in=180] to (!2.west) (!2.east) [out=0, in=-145] to (!3);
    }
  },
  my arcs/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      my arc/.style={#1},
    }
  },
}
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle},
  my arc/.style={},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=4em,
    s sep=8em,
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content,
    my arcs={densely dashed},
  }
  [P_1, my circle, arc through
    [, edge label={x=0}]
    [P_2, my circle, edge label=x
      [{c-x,x}, edge label=Y]
      [{0,0}, edge label=N]
    ]
    [, edge label={x=c}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

---

## EDIT ASIDE

This version is just for [Clément](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292575/improve-tree-aspect-forest?noredirect=1#comment708816_292575). Although it is more than 546 characters, it is still only 644. And Kile makes the TikZ-only code 563 characters, so probably my statistics is counting characters differently.

Personally, I don't think this an advantage, but there you are.

It is not very transparent so I don't actually recommend using this.

However, the way the arc is drawn is much neater than my earlier code. What I'd probably do is base `arc below` on this method rather than using the `through` library.

The main saving in characters is achieved by eliminating automation. The edge labels are no longer placed automatically according to the position of the child relative to its siblings. So, if you add a node, you have to check if any `left`s should become `right`s or vice-versa. Moreover, no style is used for the circles, reducing flexibility and maintainability of the code. Finally, dollar signs are used for the content of nodes rather than `math content` because `math content,` contains more characters than the number required to assign a pair of dollar signs to each node which needs them.

Ironically, the drawing of the arc actually now uses **forest** features more heavily and TikZ features less heavily. (`y()` is used with a pgfmath wrapper to get the information needed for the arc, rather than relying on the `through` library.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  ey/.style={shape=coordinate,no edge},
  elr/.style 2 args={edge label={node[midway,outer sep=1.5mm,#1]{$#2$}}},
  el/.style={elr={left}{#1}},
  er/.style={elr={right}{#1}},
  for tree={l sep=4em,s sep=8em,calign=fixed edge angles}
  [$P_1$,draw,circle
    [,el={x=0},ey]
    [$P_2$,draw,circle,er=x,anchor=north,before drawing tree={TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={\gdef\rs{#1}}{y("!u")-y()}},tikz={\draw(!u)--($(!u)!1!-35:(.north)$)arc(235:305:\rs pt)--(!u);}
      [${c-x,x}$,el=Y]
      [${0,0}$,er=N]]
    [,er={x=c},ey]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: short and sour version]

Comment: Definitely , an incredible way of doing it. However, I cannot where/how you make the branches of the second node smaller.

Comment: @Héctor I planned to adjust either `l` or `l sep`. However, it didn't seem necessary so I didn't do anything. The tree just automatically came out this way. I'm curious as to why as well.

Comment: I think it is just a side-effect of the `nice empty nodes`.

Comment: @Héctor Please see edit above.

Answer (score 6):

I know you want to stick to `forest` but while you wait for an answer with it, you can try to understand a poor man way of drawing your scheme. It's not so difficult:

Let's draw `P1` somewhere

```
\node[circle,draw] (P1) {$P_1$};
```

Let's draw `P2` at a certain known distance below `P1`

```
\node[circle, draw, on grid, below = 2cm of P1, anchor=north] (P2) {$P_2$};
```

with `on grid` and `anchor=north` we force a `2cm` distance between P1's center and P2's north. We will need it for a perfect arc.

Now we can draw the line between `P1` and `P2`

```
\draw (P1)-- node[right]{$x$} (P2);
```

Next, decide which angles you want for left and right children. The arm length will be `2cm` starting from `P1` center. At the end of right child, we draw the arc because we know initial angle, final angle and radius.

```
\draw (P1) -- node[right] {$x=c$} ++ (-60:2cm) arc (-60:-120:2cm);
\draw (P1) -- node[left] {$x=0$} ++ (240:2cm);
```

And we finish with `P2` children using similar commands:

```
\draw (P2) -- node[right] {$N$} ++ (-60:2cm) node[below] {$0,0$};
\draw (P2) -- node[left] {$Y$} ++ (240:2cm) node[below] {$c-x,x$};
```

That's all. The result:

[image]

and complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\node[circle,draw] (P1) {$P_1$};
\node[circle, draw, on grid, below = 2cm of P1, anchor=north] (P2) {$P_2$};
\draw (P1)-- node[right]{$x$} (P2);

\draw (P1) -- node[right] {$x=c$} ++ (-60:2cm) arc (-60:-120:2cm);
\draw (P1) -- node[left] {$x=0$} ++ (240:2cm);

\draw (P2) -- node[right] {$N$} ++ (-60:2cm) node[below] {$0,0$};
\draw (P2) -- node[left] {$Y$} ++ (240:2cm) node[below] {$c-x,x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Partly because this could actually be wrapped into the `forest` environment. That is, the same basic idea is how I get the arc in my answer. Also this is, I think, easier to understand than a **forest** answer.  Actually, yours is simpler because I really don't need `through`. (I thought I did and then forgot why I thought I needed it, I think.) But drawing many trees this way would nonetheless be extremely tedious and prone to error. If you wanted to change the angles for all trees, you could use regex, of course, but it isn't as easy as changing a couple of numbers in the preamble.

Comment: Actually, maybe I do need `through`. Otherwise, the calculations seem slightly off. Or I'm missing something ;). Probably the latter.

Comment: To get arrows, as in the picture posted by OP, simple replace `\draw (P1)` by `\draw [->] (P1)` and `\draw (P2)` by `\draw [->] (P2)`.

Comment: @cfr I was expecting your `forest` answer ;-) I know `forest` **is** the tool for trees but only for this particular case I thought that a basic `TiKZ` solution was not bad and not too difficult to understand. About `through` or not (I've never used it), I could solve the arc problem with `on grid`.

Comment: This is certainly a beautiful and short piece of code that generates a lovely output. Now I know I can rely on TikZ if I get stuck with Forest in the future. For now, though, I think I'll use the solutions that use Forest because this is more familiar for me.

Comment: @Ignasi It would probably be possible to use that with **forest** but it would require manually adjusting the node placement. Taking the default and using the `through` library seemed simpler in the `forest` environment.

Comment: @Héctor You can always use the TikZ stuff in addition. For example, you can add stuff after the final closing bracket, as well as using keys like `tikz` and `afterthought`.

Answer (score 4):

1. The "white space" is nothing more than empty nodes. Even though you didn't add text, the nodes are created therefore in turn creating the white space. To solve this, simply add `coordinate` to the options for those nodes, like `name=1, coordinate,...`
2. Solved by the next point.
3. For the angles, add `calign=fixed edge angles` to your `for tree={}` options.
4. I can't find a way to do this, not even in the manual. I think I'm missing something obvious.

In any case, here's the current result:

[image]

Comment: Lovely. Minimum changes and desires output. Now I only need how to make the branches of the second node shorter.

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit: `istgame` vesion 2.0

With the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) version 2.0, you can have more controls on the arc type continuum of branches:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}    
\begin{istgame}[->,font=\footnotesize]
\cntmdistance{15mm}{30mm}
\cntmAistb[->]{x=0}[al]{x=1}[ar]
\cntmApreset[ultra thin]<1.5>
\istrootcntmA(0)[null node]{1}
  \istbA{x}[r]
  \endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{20mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1)[null node]<45>{2}
  \istb{Y}[l]{c-x,x}
  \istb{N}[r]{0,0}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original answer

This is another solution to get the form of the `ultimatum` game you want, by using the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package. (You can find yet another way of drawing the ultimatum game in its package document.) Since the `istgame` environment is almost the same as the `tikzpicture`, you can use tikz `macros` within the `istgame` environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}    
\begin{istgame}[->,font=\footnotesize]
\istroot(0)[null node]{1}+15mm..15mm+
  \istb{x=0}[l]
  \istb<level distance=1.42*15mm>{x}[r]
  \istb{x=c}[r]
  \endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{20mm}
\istroot(1)(0-2)[null node]<45>{2}
  \istb{Y}[l]{c-x,x}
  \istb{N}[r]{0,0}
  \endist
\draw[-,ultra thin,tension=1] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0-1)(0-2)(0-3)};
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```